# Twisted Python Google Drive API for Tahoe-LAFS

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am planning on creating a Twisted Python Google Drive API using the open-source txboxdotnet API as a base, which is based on Box.com's API and is located [here](https://github.com/mk-fg/txboxdotnet).
Doing this would allow me to create a plugin for Tahoe-LAFS, a Least Authority File System which gives the user a number of additional client-side security functions. For my purposes, I am using the open-source branch of Tahoe-LAFS that allows for cloud interaction located [here](https://github.com/LeastAuthority/tahoe-lafs/tree/1819-cloud-merge-opensource) and an open-source public-clouds modification made for this branch.
My main question is would the creation of a Twisted Python API for Google Drive be allowed under the Terms and Conditions for Google Developers?  The API will (of course) not contain any of my confidential developer credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Well going on the assumption of best practices here and your description of the API usage and intent you are within the bounds of their terms. You can read for yourself [here](https://developers.google.com/terms/). Sections 3 and 4 to be exact.